# Different CSS items not in line

Tags: html, css

I have a `h1 a` element and many `li a` elements that I would like to put in the same line.

My problem is that the `h1` is aligned at the top, while the rest are aligned at the baseline.

`h1` shows a display block,
`h1 a` shows a display inline,
`ul` shows a display block,
`ul li` shows a display list-item,
`ul li a` shows a display inline.

http://jsfiddle.net/jz2ufv5a/

HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <div id="logo">
         <h1>
            <a href="#">Studio</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 60px 0 120px 0;
    font-family:'PT Mono';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    color: #444;
}
#logo {
    background-color: #f32;
    float: left;
}
#logo h1 {
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}
#logo a {
    color: inherit !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #f3f;
    float: right;
}
#menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited {
    color:#444;
}
#menu a:hover, #menu a:focus, #menu a:active, #menu a.currentPage {
    color:#fed356;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i updated the question with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's the default `margin` that gets applied to `ul` elements. It's good practice to use some kind of CSS reset. I typically just set `padding: 0; margin: 0;` globally on all elements. Add:

```
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/53annn6r/)